# Sum of a column excluding duplicate join records

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, duplicates, sum

Let's say I have a table containing cities with their populations and a table containing buildings of different types. I want to know the percentage of people living in cities containing schools.

Cities:

| name | pop |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 100 |
| C | 1000 |

Buildings:

| is_school | city |
| --- | --- |
| false | A |
| true | B |
| true | B |
| true | C |

If I do somthing like:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN building.is_school = true THEN city.pop ELSE 0 END) school,
  SUM(city.pop) total
FROM city
LEFT JOIN building ON building.city = city.name;
```

I get city B population summed twice.
I would like to have:

| school | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1100 | 1110 |

but I get:

| school | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1200 | 1210 |

[fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=51f3ea84-96a8-47fc-963c-6c0933f5bb42)

I can do a subquery:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN city.name in (
    SELECT city.name
    FROM city
    LEFT JOIN building ON building.city = city.name
    WHERE building.is_school = true
  ) THEN city.pop ELSE 0 END),
  SUM(city.pop)
FROM city;
```

but it feels unnecessary convoluted considering what I'm trying to achieve, is there really no other way ?

Comment: Sample table data is great, but a [mcve] is supposed to include the expected result as well.

Comment: added expected result + fiddle

Comment: why you just remove the duplicated record? I can't understand why it's there if you are not using it anyway

Comment: Certainly a city can have many building types, where some or none are schools. These sample data do not seem realistic. So what do you want for an answer if City B has both Schools and Non-School buildings?

Comment: Use aggregate `filter` clause. You don't need to `sum(case when X then Y else 0 end)`, you can just `sum(Y)filter(where X)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```sql
SELECT
  1.0 * sum(case when exists (
  select 1 from building b where b.city = c.name and is_school) then 1 else 0 end)
  / count(*)
FROM city c;
```

Result:

```
?column?
--------
0.66666666666666666667
```

Or, you can use a lateral join:

```sql
select 1.0 * sum(coalesce(n, 0)) / count(*) as p
from city c
left join lateral (
  select 1 from building b where b.city = c.name and b.is_school limit 1
) x (n) on true
```

See running examples at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Il-FhzWs).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use is to join with a **filtered version of buildings** instead of building itself

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN building.is_school = true THEN city.pop ELSE 0 END) school, SUM(city.pop) total
FROM city
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT city, is_school FROM building) building ON building.city = city.name;
```

It is not recommended to use **DISTINCT** for huge database, since the process of determining distinct records is very slow, but at least the query is slim and cute

Answer (score 0):

You need to pre-aggregate the join in some way, either by using an `EXISTS` or `LIMIT`, or you can just use `GROUP BY` in a subquery.

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN b.city IS NOT NULL THEN c.pop END) school,
  SUM(c.pop) total
FROM city c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      b.city
    FROM building b
    WHERE b.is_school
    GROUP BY b.city
) b ON b.city = c.name;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/dr-T_8QC)